# Windows 10 bash.exe (linux user space) does not exist when checked from 32 bit app

Tags: winapi, windows-10

When 32bit app like java or python is trying to open `c:\windows\system32\bash.exe` this file simply not found.

How ever, it works perfectly if process ir 64bit. I've created a simple C app to check how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char* path;
OFSTRUCT junk;

if (argc  != 2) {
 printf("provide path to file");
 return 1;
}
path = argv[1];
if( fopen( path, "r")) {
    printf("OK: Runtime reports file exists");
} else {
    printf("ERR: Runtime reports file does not exist");
}

printf("\n");
if (OpenFile(path, &junk,OF_EXIST) != HFILE_ERROR) {
    printf("OK: Win32API reports file exists");
} else {
    printf("ERR: Win32API reports file does not exist");
}

return 0;
```

}

It reports OK/OK when compiled and linked as x64 and ERR/ERR when compiled as x86. How could it be? Does there is some way to "hide" file from 32 bit apps in Windows?

Comment: This is the [file system redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) in action.

Comment: please post as comment, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [file system redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) in action.

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64.

So, your 32-bit application is looking for `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bash.exe` instead, which presumably doesn't exist.

The recommended way to override it:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access.

Note that there are similar redirections for the [registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thank you again. I've never thought about it. Now I will read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274(v=vs.85).aspx carefully.